Was the domain "zlibrary-bl.se" actually seized by the US Government's FBI (Federal Bureau of Investigation) through international law?
Question: Was the domain "zlibrary-bl.se" actually seized by the US Government?

http://web.archive.org/web/20241109063932/https://zlibrary-bl.se/
The website appears to be poorly formatted and potentially of a comical nature. As thus, I question its validity.

It doesn't look that weird compared to images of other seized websites, except for the bottom section of "Z-Library is stealing from..." and the images. Perhaps copy the image here, in any case?

I think an alternative forum would be better than "Politics".  Perhaps [Law.se]  (you are asking about an act of law enforcement), Perhaps [Skeptics.se] (if there is a notable claim to be tested) or Perhaps [Ebooks.se] (if z-library was a library of e-books?)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-Library

The same question in Skeptics SE: Is this web-site a Z-Library site that was seized by the FBI?
